# Testing value change of TextInput in React Native with Jest

Tags: react-native, jestjs

I have a `TextInput` component, which calls a custom function when its value changes through its `onValueChange` property.

Is it possible to simulate the change of the text of this `TexInput` with Jest, so that I test if that the custom function (which is passed as a prop) is called with correct parameters and produces correct results?

Answer (score 1):

Yes its possible with jest and enzyme. Below is the definition of SearchBar component which receives a function as a prop. The function is called with the text typed.

```
const SearchBar = ({onSearch}) => {
  return (
    <View>
      <TextInput
        onChangeText={text => onSearch(text)}
      />
    </View>
  );
};
```

The testing can be carried as follows

```
    const onSearch = jest.fn();
    const wrapper = shallow(<SearchBar onSearch={onSearch} />);
    wrapper.find('TextInput').simulate('changeText', 'test search text');
    expect(onSearch).toHaveBeenCalledWith('test search text');
```